# Email personalization when sending to Salesforce report or campaign

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect, campaign, custom-reports

How can we personalize the emails when sending to Salesforce Report or Campaign? 
How do we use personalization strings with data from Salesforce as Reports and Campaigns?
or should we directly use AMPscript ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only fields that you have already configured and mapped in your [Field Mapping](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_map_attribute_fields.htm&type=5) will be available.

Your other three options are:

1. Using a [Lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) or [LookupRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm) on the synchronized DE
2. Or a [RetrieveSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm)
3. Or [importing the campaign or report](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_import_activity.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) into a sendable data extension.

Examples:

```
LookupRows('ZipCode','City',HomeCity)

%%[ var @rs

Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Id, FirstName,LastName', 'region', '=', 'west','AnnualRevenue', '>', '1000000')

]%%
```

Comment: Hello @JacksonChen Thank you! What is the process for importing or sending Campaign/report data into a data extension ? is there a convenient feature for that with the connector ? (instead of of extract the file corresponding to the Campaign or report data and import them into a data extension) Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use the Import Activity to do this.

Comment: OK, so there is no feature that allows to directly "send" SF campaign or report data directly into a Data Extension in SFMC with the Marketing cloud connector ?